# Laravel 4 Log Errors: NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following appearing in my log files and being a new comer to Laravel, I'm not sure where to start debugging. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
[2013-12-23 01:04:41] log.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in /home/ulti/laravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php:5125
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ulti/laravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php(4970): Illuminate\Routing\Router->handleRoutingException(Object(Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException))
#1 /home/ulti/laravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php(4958): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 /home/ulti/laravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php(534): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /home/ulti/laravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php(521): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 /home/ulti/public_html/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#5 {main} [] []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this means is that you visited a route that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that was the case but figured I'd better be sure. It's a large site which is also a redesign so there will be many such visits to old routes that no longer exist.

Answer (score 0):

This means you have an invalid route. This is saying "Hey this page doesn't exist!". The page might exist but due to how routes are defined, and that controllers aren't routed automatically, it may not function as you expect. Can you post the code that has your routes, and also the URL you're trying to go to on site? That would be a start to help you with debugging! :)